# find php file with x length or less than x length

Tags: find

I want to find php files with 3 characters long or less than it. eg ..php, a.php, cc.php, abc.php etc. I know how to find exactly x lenght of file by following command. For example if I want to find 3 characters long php files and dump all the result to a file I'll do

```
# find . -type f -name "???.php" >> results.txt
```

I just need a little tweak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
find . -name "*.php" |grep "/.\{1,3\}\.php" >> results.txt
```

Comment: Yes! nice tweak, works fine. Thanks!! I didn't make use of pipeline and grep.

Comment: It seems that "find" doesn't offer a regex-search, so I tried it "old school". ;-)

Comment: @AndreasGnyp Newer version of both `gnu` and `bsd` `find` do offer `-regex`. Also a couple of minor issues. Your command will fail if filenames contain `EOL` or `/.\{1,3\}\.php` anywhere in the path (i.e. not at the end). Consider adding a `-print0` and reading a null terminated list (`-exec` without piping would also work), and using something like `egrep` that can check for an end of the path `$`.

Comment: @BroSlow Yes, it came to me, after posting, that the $ would be a good addition here. But, since it's quite unlikely - in his scenario, and also figured, he would manage - I didn't edit my post. Thank you for pointing out the regex switch, must have missed it. Upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

globs should be good enough

```
find -type f \( -name "?.php" -o -name "??.php" -o -name "???.php" \)  >> results.txt
```

Or if you want regex

```
find -type f -regextype 'posix-basic' -regex '.*/[^/]\{1,3\}\.php$' >> results.txt
```